# HTML Print Area style in Modal

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I'm confused when i want to print modal body area and directly print on modalarea to fit paper of 58mm

here the output [image] and in the page of print chrome the output cant fit [image]

here my code `

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Print Nota ' . $data_barang["id_pembelian"] . '</title>
     <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        @media print {
            @page {
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }

            html,
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            #printContainer {
                margin: left;
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: justify;
                font-size: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onLoad="javascript:window.print();">
    <div id="printContainer">
        <div style="line-height: normal;">
            <div style="text-align:center;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 20px;">
                <img src="' . base_url('assets/logo_injaya.png').'" width="50" height="50" alt="Logo">
            </div>`
```

my expect the output result fit on paper on 58mm size

[image]